# How find the polynomial such $(P(x))^m$ with the coefficient is postive

Tags: polynomials

**Question:**
Given a nonconstant polynomial P with at least one negative coefficient, 
then $(P(x))^m\forall m\in N^{+},m\ge 2$ with  all coefficient is postive.

in other words:

> Prove :There exsit real coefficient polynomial
>   $$P(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0},n\ge 1$$
>   where there exsit some coefficient is negative.
>
> and
>   such
>   $$(P(x))^m=b_{nm}x^{nm}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0},\forall m\in N^{+},m\ge 2$$
>
> where $b_{i}>0,i=1,\cdots,nm$

I fell maybe this polynomial is not exsit,But I can't prove it? Thank you

My try:if let  $$P(x)=x-1,\Longrightarrow (P(x))^2=x^2-2x+1,(P(x))^3=x^3-3x^2+3x+1,\cdots$$
this example is not such this condition

if $$P(x)=x^2-x+1,\Longrightarrow (P(x))^2=x^4-2x^3+3x^2-2x+1$$
also not such condition

Comment: Hint: [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Comment: Are you asking the following question?: Given a nonconstant polynomial $P$ with at least one negative coefficient, must every power of $P$ also have at least one negative coefficient? (The question wording is very, very vague, but this is my best guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(3x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x+3)^2=9x^8+18x^7+3x^6+12x^5+37x^4+12x^3+3x^2+18x+9$$ is an example that works for $m=2$. Maybe it works for all $m$.